# Map 410874 frames to time limits between 0 and 2062637 with a length of 10ms for each frame

Tags: matlab, time, matrix, match, frame

I have 410874 frames each of which I want to map between a time limit between 0 and 2062637 with a length of 10ms interval. so that after the process each frame will be matched against a time as given below

```
1 0
2 10
3 20
4 50
5 60
6 70
. .
. .
. .
410874 2062637
```

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're having?

Comment: Your numbers don't match! With a 10-ms step, frame 410784 should have time 4107830 ms, not 2062637 ms. ??

Comment: I have frames from a wave file and label files for times between 0 to 2062637. so I want to match the frame to a time from with a difference of 10ms between each frame

Comment: I think that the question is how to drop frames in order to make the movie that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at [linspace(a,b,n)](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), this should be easy for you :)

you can simply make a vector of 410874 elements which span from 0 to 2062637 by using

```
t=linspace(0,2062637,410874);
```

although the points will only be ~5ms from eachother not 10ms as you stated because 2062637 / 410874 =  5.0201, so if you want 10ms you have to reduce the number of elements

```
t=t(1:2:end)
```

or

```
t=0:10:2062637;
```

the later will give you a 1x2062640 array, again cause those numbers dont fit your specifications.

Comment: q=linspace(0,10,410874); gives me values like 
0
2.43384208745768e-05
4.86768417491536e-05
7.30152626237305e-05
9.73536834983073e-05
0.000121692104372884
0.000146030525247461
0.000170368946122038

Comment: `linspace(a,b,n)` generates a vector of n points linearly spaced between and including a and b. b is no stepsize but a limit, still your numbers don't match up to have evenly distributed points in 10ms distance of eachother